# Adding map of httpheaders to builder

Tags: java

I'm building a `HttpRequest` with where I want to supply the request with a map of headers: `Map<String, List<String>>`.

**Problem**
The `HttpRequest` builder only takes headers as a key(String) value(String) and not as whole map. How can I supply the contents of the map to the `headers` in the builder?

```
HttpRequest httpRequest = java.net.http.HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .uri(URI.create("google.com"))
        .headers("String", "String")
        .GET()
        .build();
```

Comment: There's a `header` method -- see the Javadoc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpRequest.Builder.html) say there is another ovlerload `headers​(String... headers)`. It *Adds the given name value pairs to the set of headers for this request. The supplied String instances must alternate as header names and header values. To add several values to the same name then the same name must be supplied with each new value.*

You'd need to convert the map `Map<String, List<String>>`, say {"a" -> (1,2), "b"->3} to a String[] {"a", 1, "a", 2, "b", 3}}

Flattening the map to the array should work like this:

```
public static String[] flattenMap(Map<String, List<String>> m) {
    return m.entrySet().stream().flatMap(x ->
            x.getValue().stream().flatMap(y -> Stream.of(x.getKey(), y)))
            .toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
    public static HttpRequest.Builder addHeaders(HttpRequest.Builder builder, Map<String, List<String>> headers) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> e : headers.entrySet()) {
            for (String value : e.getValue()) {
                builder.header(e.getKey(), value);
            }
        }
        return builder;
    }
```

With less flatMap 'magic' :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that:

```
Map<String, String> HEADERS = Map.of("Authorization", "Basic xyz==");
HttpRequest.Builder httpRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder(URI.create("example.com"));
HEADERS.forEach(httpRequest::header);
```